# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS autostart script started from rc.local doesn't execute ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, ubuntu

I got a strange problem.

My setting:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Self written shell scripts and one ruby script (ending `*.rb`) in a folder on the desktop.

I realized the autostart by using the file `/etc/rc.local` where I added the path to the startup script:

```
[...]
sh /home/username/Desktop/shell/startup.sh
exit 0
```

There are no other scripts in that file.

So here, the `startup.sh` executes then the rest.
1. another shell script.
2. the ruby file
3. a sendmail shellcript
4. shutdown script

Everything is executed fine, but not the ruby script.

The strange thing is, that it works perfectly when I start the startup.sh from the terminal.

I checked the paths, the read/write permissions, the owner,... but nothing works.
I also tried to execute the `startup.sh` by using the `rcX.d` files but I got the same result.
I added a sleep timer in the `rc.local` to be sure that everything is loaded in the background.

Using gnome-system-monitor I can see the rc.local executing each file but at least it goes to the shutdown script.

The scripts are not executed at the same time, all after the other.

Everything I tried didn't work. the ruby script is "ignored".

I hope you can help me because I have no ideas any more.

greetings,
miles

**UPDATE:**

*rc.local*

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sleep 3m
../home/milesdavis/Desktop/shell/startup.sh
exit 0
```

*startup.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby /home/milesdavis/Desktop/shell/myrubyscript.rb
sh /home/milesdavis/Desktop/shell/shutdown.sh
```

*myrubyscript.rb*

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'glib2'
require 'gtk2'
require 'vte'
require 'rexml/document'
...
```

*shutdown.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
shutdown -h 10
```

I like to say again that it goes directly to the shutdown script and executes that.

Comment: startup.sh should exec the ruby script? Post the relevant commands. Is the ruby script executable or do you call it with the ruby interpreter? How does the first line of the ruby script look like (shebang).

Comment: yes, the `rc.local` executes `startup.sh` it does the rest. The content of `startup.sh` is just a list of other scripts that are executed. And one these is my ruby file. Rights: everything is root:root and executable. The first line of my ruby file is `#!/usr/bin/ruby`. I know that this line can be different but I checked the path.

Comment: please post the relevant commands/code.

Comment: Which commands do you mean? I am relative new to ruby/shell programming but now I think that at the moment where my rc.local runs the startup.sh and comes to the ruby script it seems that ruby isn't loaded yet. Could that be? I am not able to check that but I think that could be a reason...

Comment: Okay, easiest is to post your startup.sh and the ruby-script in complete. If not possible, post the relevant parts (first view lines and the line calling the ruby script).

Comment: The complete ruby file is useless here, but the calls are posted above. There's nothing special about the `startup.sh`. The paths are all absolute and not relative (I tried both ways). For testing I turned off all script executions that come before the ruby line because they are not dependent from the ruby file so that was no problem. So I am pretty sure that it has something to do with ruby - I think there are several libs or so that are not yet available or not yet initialized or however at the time the rc.local tries to execute the `startup.sh`.

Comment: The path to the ruby executable is not absolute (e.g. /usr/bin/ruby or /home/you/.rvm/ ... ). Also, if the ruby script is executable you could skip the executable (but try with absolute path to interpreter first). Also, use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

Comment: if I type in `which ruby` it says `/usr/bin/ruby`, but why `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`?

Comment: What did you do to find an answer to that question? There is e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my . I use rvm to manage multiple rubies, using /usr/bin/env always picks the ruby I asked rvm to use. Did the scripts work when you specify the full path to ruby (`/usr/bin/ruby /home/milesdavis/Desktop/shell/myrubyscript.rb`)?

Comment: I solved it by removing the stuff from the rc.local. I used the standard autostart widget and added my script. It works now. The main problem was that the bash started correctly too early. It needs gtk and at that time the necessary files are not yet available so the script breaks and it jumps to the shutdown script. So, simply but It was really annoying but finally I am happy. Thank you for your help anyway! Best greestings, miles